# An efficient way to find the value of a key in range

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, range, bioinformatics

I'm working on a genome whose length (number of positions) is around 90,000,000. I have a list of positions ranges and their values like this:

```
start     end  value
    0   12673      0
12673   27348      3
27348   29473      4
29473  121904      0
...
```

which means for example in position 12910 (which is between 12673 and 27348) the value is 3.
How can I search for the value of any of my desired positions?

I made a dictionary of positions (as keys) and values (as values) which search is O(1) but this method is really RAM-consuming. Can some one please suggest me some better approach?

Comment: maybe consider using database?

Comment: Generally speaking: Is it consuming considerably more RAM than you have? Because it does not get any better than O(1). Everything is a trade-off between speed and memory consumption. If you switch to something that uses less RAM, be prepared to wait longer for results.

Comment: @Tomalak For huge genomes it surpasses my RAM. Currently I switched to an o(n) code but I think there may be an efficient o(1) way! :)

Comment: I plan to use "xz-ordering a space-filling curve for objects with spatial extension" to solve this problem in a generic way. There is an implementation in scala in the wild. Other space filling curve might be easier to implement. Basically, the problem you are trying to solve is a problem of geometry.

Comment: Maybe the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module is usable for this.